# Why is Modulo 2 optimization different from x&1?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, signed, integer-division

Why is the assembly output of this code:

*code*

```c
int 
f(int n) {
        return n % 2;
}
```

**asm**

```
f:
        mov     edx, edi
        shr     edx, 31
        lea     eax, [rdi+rdx]
        and     eax, 1
        sub     eax, edx
        ret
```

different from this one:

*code*

```c
int 
g(int n) {
        return n & 1;
}
```

**asm**

```
g:
        mov     eax, edi
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

I couldn't find anything online (maybe I didn't use the right keywords).

NOTE:

- compiler: `gcc`
- args: `-O3`

Comment: Compare the output of f and g for argument `-1`

Comment: @Mat right, it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: To complete what@Mat said, to be pedantic, in first case you get the remainder, in second case the modulo

Comment: If you use `unsigned`, the compiler can optimize to just an AND.

Comment: @PeterCordes Correct. That idea came into my mind after testing with Mats value.